# Java specific layout

Tags: java, layout

I need to design layout in my application like this:

[image: desired layout]

But I don't know how to achieve this. I've tried GridBagLayout because it seems like way to go but I can't achieve stretching some panel to more cells than layout actually contains. I mean let's say that layout on picture should be 8:6, panel 1 should be [6:4], panel 2 [1,6], panel3 [6,2], panels 4,5,6 [1:2]. Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: why not try using BoxLayout? try splitting the base panel into 3 boxes horizontally, then split the left box into two vertically and right box into three vertically - et voila. you can do it in many different ways, but this is (arguably) the easiest.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to use a single layout to do all the work, keep in mind that you can **nest** layouts by putting JPanels with XYZ layout inside of a JPanel with ABC layout.

There are any number of ways to use nested layouts to achieve this effect. Try breaking your window down into different sections: the [4, 5, 6] boxes could be a JPanel with a BoxLayout, for example. Then you just need to worry about how to position that BoxLayout in the bigger picture: maybe in a FlowLayout with the [2] component? And then you might put that FlowLayout into a BorderLayout along with [1, 3]?

Like I said, there are a ton of different ways to achieve the effect, and you need to break it down in a way that makes sense to you.

Recommended reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

And here is another tutorial on layouts and nested layouts: http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/swing/layouts

Comment: `+1` for `There are any number of ways to use nested layouts to achieve this effect.` - that's clearly the most important fact here, the UI should be designed based on its *goals*, if it has to be dynamic (scaling etc) then one has to figure the glues, spacers etc too, no easy way to skip it.